# How do you require users to be logged in on asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am new to asp.net Identity and I cannot seem to figure out how to only allow logged in users to access certain pages in my controllers. All the documentation I am reading seems dated. Basically I would like to forward the user to a login page when they make a request to the server which runs one of the specified controller functions like so

```
       //How do I prevent anonymous user from preforming this model action
       //Unless they are logged in

       [HttpPost]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SomeModelAction([Bind("ID,AModelField,UserID")] AModel aModel)
        {
         //code to preform action on a model

            return View(aModel);
        }
```

Comment: Side note: for product that was created 15+ years ago it is somewhat strange to expect all documentation to be very recent...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am just learning the framework sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `[Authorize]` attribute to a class or method you'd like to be available only to authenticated users.

Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles) for some up-to-date documentation and a few examples.

Comment: Worked great! Thank you

Comment: Side note - linking to documentation for ASP.Net-core when question is about regular ASP.Net is somewhat questionable.

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted to help others find it in the future. Thanks!